# Add commas between character

Tags: r

I'm calling in an argument with optparse, but I'm needing the format of the resulting argument (variable `x`) to be what is listed below:

```
# Set up command line arguments 

library("optparse")

option_list = list(
  make_option(c("--test"), type="character", default=NULL, 
              help="test", metavar="character")

opt_parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list);
opt = parse_args(opt_parser);

# grab argument into x variable

x <- (opt$pathcsv)
print(x)
```

Entering the command line :

```
Rscript --vanilla riboeclip_ma.R --pathcsv="test test2 test3"
```

output is a character type:

```
"test test2 test3"
```

How can I get the output of x variable to be `"test", "test2", "test3"` without affecting how the command line argument is given.

Answer (score 1):

You may split the `x` value on whitespace and `unlist` to get a vector of string.

```
x <- (opt$pathcsv)
#x <- "test test2 test3"
x1 <- unlist(strsplit(x, '\\s+'))
x2 <- paste0(sprintf('"%s"', x1), collapse = ',')
x2
#[1] "\"test\",\"test2\",\"test3\""
```

While displaying R escapes quotes, the real string can be viewed by `cat`.

```
cat(x2)
#"test","test2","test3"
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, this gives me "test"  "test2"

but I'm looking for something like this "test",  "test2" (split by comma)

Comment: How about `x1 <- gsub('\\s+', ',', x)` ? Replacing whitespace with comma.

Comment: This is giving me the same, [1] "test"  "test2" "test3"

Which is typeof character

Comment: If `x` is `x <- "test test2 test3"` and you do `x1 <- gsub('\\s+', ',', x)`. It gives `x1` as `"test,test2,test3"`. and yes class will be of type character.

Comment: The way my script takes in the values though, I would need "test", " test2", "test3" (basically quotations separated by commas). The script won't work as "test,test2,test3" for input because there are no quotations between them. I'm trying to automate this process.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
toString(dQuote(strsplit(x, "\\s+")[[1]], FALSE))
[1] "\"test\", \"test2\", \"test3\""
```

#### data

```
x <- (opt$pathcsv)
x <- "test test2 test3"
```